# Programmatically resolve LAN computer name to fully qualified name?

Tags: c++, winapi, dns, winsock

I'm writing a C++ app which receives a LAN computer name as input from the exterior world (e.g. \\PCNAME123, which I can access by typing in the Windows run prompt or in the IE address bar) and needs to get some data based on that name, for instance by calling the `gethostbyname()` function with it.

Problem is that I need to have what I think is called (I'm new to Winsock and network programming in general so I might not have the terminology right) a fully qualified name (e.g. PCNAME123.domainname.net). I have tested it, `gethostbyname()` works ok with that but not with "PCNAME123" or "\\PCNAME123".

How do I get the fully qualified name of that network computer (please note that it's not for the localhost but for other computers on the local network)?

Comment: Unless you have additional information (such as "it is a member of the AD domain" or "it is in the same DNS domain as I am") it is logically impossible to convert an unqualified name to a qualified one, for the simple reason that two (or more) computers can have the same unqualified name so how would you tell which one to choose?

Comment: The same way Internet Explorer or the Run prompt does? I'm ok with the same behaviour of the Run prompt or IE when "ambiguous" unqualified names are given.

Comment: My mistake, I'd missed the qualifier that the machines were on the local network.  That makes things easier, for a start the machines will likely complain if anyone tries to set up duplicate names. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with GetAddrInfoW function to get name information.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, looks like one of the solutions is to use `getaddrinfo()` function.

Comment: This should work provided that the target computer is in one of the DNS domains that are on your computer's search path.  If more than one computer of the same name is on the search path, I'm not sure whether you'll get all of them or just one chosen at random.

Comment: Come to think of it, it probably also works for machines on the local network (whether or not DNS is configured) provided that both machines (your machine and the target machine) are configured to treat the local network as a "private" or "work" network rather than "public". +1.